# how to implement eclipse like tab in Extjs4

Tags: layout, extjs

I have a several panels which layout is vbox and hbox
how can I implement maximum and minimum feature when dbclick the panel title
here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SLHjn/

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
style: 'padding:0 10px 0 10px',
layout: {
    align: 'stretch',
    type: 'vbox'
},
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    border: 0,
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 100,
        title: 'title1',
        html: 'panel1'              
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 100,
        title: 'title2',
        html: 'panel2'  
    }]
}, {
    xtype: 'panel',
    border: 0,
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'title3',
        height: 100,
        flex: 1,
        html: 'panel3'              
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'title3',
        flex: 1,
        html: 'panel4'  
    }]
  }]
});
```

I have two problems:

1. how to add dbclick event on panel title
2. if use collapse and expand, when dbclick on panel1, how to set panel3 and panel4 collapse top:
   http://jsfiddle.net/SLHjn/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `dblclick` event on the outer panel, then use `toggleCollapse` function, like below.

**REMARK:**
Do not use `collapse` and `expand` function which will not work. Juts use `toggleCollapse`

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    style: 'padding:0 10px 0 10px',
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        border: 0,
        layout: {
            align: 'stretch',
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100,
            title: 'title1',
            html: 'panel1',
            listeners: {
                dblclick: {
                    fn: function() {
                        var pnl = Ext.getCmp('panel-out');
                        pnl.toggleCollapse();
                    },
                    element: 'el'
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100,
            title: 'title2',
            html: 'panel2'  
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        border: 0,
        id: 'panel-out',
        layout: {
            align: 'stretch',
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'title3',
            height: 100,
            flex: 1,
            html: 'panel3'              
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'title3',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'panel4'  
        }]
    }]
});
```

**UPDATE:**
then, try this (I am just hide and show the panel )

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    style: 'padding:0 10px 0 10px',
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        border: 0,
        layout: {
            align: 'stretch',
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100,
            title: 'title1',
            html: 'panel1',
            listeners: {
                dblclick: {
                    fn: function() {
                        var pnl = Ext.getCmp('panel-out');
                        pnl.toggleCollapse();
                    },
                    element: 'el'
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100,
            title: 'title2',
            html: 'panel2'  
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        border: 0,
        id: 'panel-out',
        layout: {
            align: 'stretch',
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'title3',
            height: 100,
            flex: 1,
            html: 'panel3',
            listeners: {
                dblclick: {
                    fn: function() {
                        var pnl_three = Ext.getCmp('panel4');
                        if (pnl_three.hidden == false) {
                            pnl_three.hide();
                        } else {
                            pnl_three.show();
                        }
                    },
                    element: 'el'
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'title4',
            id: 'panel4',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'panel4'  
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: thank you, that's a good way, when dbclick panel3, how to collapse panel4?